# How would I position a JComponent to true center in a BorderLayout?

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

I am developing a Swing application using `BorderLayout` to position the components. Since `BorderLayout.CENTER` positions components to whatever is left after the other components are placed, and that fact is making my GUI look weird, I was wondering if there was a way to position components to *true* center, rather than in between the two sides. Since `BorderLayout` spaces make a component fill an entire space, I'm guessing the solution would be to wrap the component into a `JPanel`. However, positioning the component to the center of this panel will make the component be closer to one side than another if you have components on other sides. How do I work around this?

These images demonstrate the problem and the ideal solution; the gray border represents the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` (wrapped in a `JPanel`) of the main frame. The black squares represents components that are throwing the center component off. The red square represents the component that needs to be centered.

Problem:

[image: Problem representation]

Ideal solution:

[image: Solution representation]

Comment: The Problem image appears more balanced and logical to me.  What, for example, should happen if the maroon rectangle were twice the width?  In the 'Ideal solution' it would overlap the black rectangle on the left.

Comment: I would suggest you to create your own implementation of LayoutManager. Simply implements `java.awt.LayoutManager` and `java.awt.LayoutManager2`, Focus on implementing the method `layoutContainer` to layout all the component within your JPanel.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The swing architecture simply wont allow that. This is from the LayoutManager java doc "Swing's painting architecture assumes the children of a JComponent do not overlap". Unless you create your own component with `isOptimizedDrawingEnabled` overiden to return false, and you also make your own LayoutManager.

Comment: @AndrewThompson the images are exaggerated to show the effect. In my application (and others), there is space for the square to be bigger.

Comment: *"..the images are exaggerated"*  So?  I minimized my example to suit the exact image shown.  Substitute triple or quadruple instead, and the original specification makes exactly as much sense (none, for those that don't already see it).

Comment: @CaffeineToCode, did you tried `BoxLayout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see the problem, in order for the red component to be centered the right and left components must be of equal size.

You might be able to use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/).

The `RelativeLayout` will allow you to make the right/left components the same size while keeping the center component at its preferred size. As the frame is resized space will be added/removed from the right/left components.

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        JPanel left = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT) );
        JPanel leftBox = new JPanel();
        leftBox.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200, 50) );
        leftBox.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
        left.add( leftBox );

        JPanel center = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER) );
        JPanel centerBox = new JPanel();
        centerBox.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(50, 50) );
        centerBox.setBackground( Color.RED );
        center.add( centerBox );

        JPanel right = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT) );
        JPanel rightBox = new JPanel();
        rightBox.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(50, 50) );
        rightBox.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
        right.add( rightBox );

        setLayout( new RelativeLayout(RelativeLayout.X_AXIS, 5) );
        add(left, new Float(1));
        add(center);
        add(right, new Float(1));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The one problem with the relative layout is that when you pack the frame the components will be dislayed too small since the preferred size is simply the sum of the components. So the left panel will be truncated.

In the example above you can add the following to get around this problem:

```
right.add( rightBox );
right.setPreferredSize( left.getPreferredSize() ); // added
```

Another option might be to use the `OverlayLayout` which can be set up to display the red panel over top of a panel containing the two other components:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        JPanel left = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT) );
        JPanel leftBox = new JPanel();
        leftBox.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200, 50) );
        leftBox.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
        left.add( leftBox );

        JPanel center = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER) );
        center.setOpaque(false);
        JPanel centerBox = new JPanel();
        centerBox.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(50, 50) );
        centerBox.setBackground( Color.RED );
        center.add( centerBox );

        JPanel right = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT) );
        JPanel rightBox = new JPanel();
        rightBox.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(50, 50) );
        rightBox.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
        right.add( rightBox );

        JPanel main = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        main.add(left, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        main.add(right, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        setLayout( new OverlayLayout(this) );
        add(center);
        add(main);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```